# Facebook change My Oauth Redirect URL

Tags: oauth, facebook-oauth

I use Facebook Oauth2.0 to login my site

redirect url: http://www.test.com/#/a/b

but the url is changed when facebook redirect, new url: http://www.test.com/?code=xxxx#/a/b

`#/a/b` is moved to the end of the link, I expected the url is:  http://www.test.com/#/a/b?code=xxxx

how can I do?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

The retuned oauth code needs to be specified as a query parameter. Therefore is it needs to be in front of the hash segment of the url.
If the # symbol should be part of the path segment of the url you need to escape it accordingly.

Comment: I use vue-route(https://router.vuejs.org/), so # symbol is required.  if # symbol is escaped, may not work properly!